# Handlers flow pattern

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

pointer dragging class containes the handlers for mouseup/mousedown/mousemove.
That is the "point of entry"...follows the mouseDown handler

```
var PointerDragging = /** @class */ (function () {
        function PointerDragging(containerEl) {
            var _this = this;
       // various props here
            this.handleMouseDown = function (ev) {
            
                if (!_this.shouldIgnoreMouse() &&
                    isPrimaryMouseButton(ev) &&
                    _this.tryStart(ev)) {
                    var pev = _this.createEventFromMouse(ev, true);
       
                    _this.emitter.trigger('pointerdown', pev);
                    _this.initScrollWatch(pev);
                    if (!_this.shouldIgnoreMove) {
                        document.addEventListener('mousemove', _this.handleMouseMove);
                    }
                    document.addEventListener('mouseup', _this.handleMouseUp);
                }
```

The above will lead to FeatureFullEmentDragging class respective handler(mousedown)..then to HitDragging class respective handler and then to DateClicking Class.

**This is the point I do not understand**...at this point the **flow will restart** from PointerDragging mouseDown handler all the way to DateSelecting Class and **then again** from Pointerdragging class...
The handlers in DateClicking and DateSelecting Class(in this example i am referring to mousedown handlers) do not have code that initiates this restart...**then which piece** of code is responsible for it?

Cause this must triggered from somehwere..but from where and why?

Comment: even if  I remove the emitter that emits events to other handlers....the PointerDown method inside pointerdragging class fires 5 times...what may be the cause of it....in addition to that some values are updated during this process

Comment: Don't add more info as comments. You have enough rep to know where the "edit" button is, I think?

Comment: Anyway it's not really clear what you're talking about. Is this your code? FullCalendar source code? Is this a [mre] of the issue? Have you stepped through the JS code with a debugger to find what code is executed? Other than basically asking us to go and read the source code for you, it's a bit unclear what the question is. Any info you want to ask about needs to be here in your post (as per the on-topic guidance).

Comment: we are talking here about FC source...code it would be difficult to provide a minimum reproducible example here cause it's a lot of code(many handlers firing)...obviously I have tried with the debugger many times....just do the following...place a breakpoint in the handleMouseDown function above...and click the mouse...and see what it happens...it fires many times.....with the PointerDragging objj having different values at some iteration...but as I said MinRepExample would be impractical/difficult.

Comment: Ok. Why do you need to know what is happening inside the FC source code? Are you trying to trace a bug, or hoping to make a modification to the code or something? You might be better to directly ask the fullCalendar developers how it works...you can raise tickets on the fullCalendar GitHub page.

Comment: Several months ago I raised an issue about a bug...it is yet to be solved by them..so I am going to deal with it myself...in order to solve  it though I must understand what the code does...I did raise an issue for the latter but they told me to post here...so far nothing..thanks though.

Comment: Ok well I don't know anything about the FC source code sorry, I only help with issues configuring / using it. AFAIK nobody who contributes regularly to the `fullcalendar` tag on SO has any such knowledge, but perhaps I'm wrong and someone will find this and help. Arguably it is still off-topic for SO though, in that the relevant info isn't really in the question, and could obviously be subject to change as the FC source changes over time, thus potentially making any answers useless for future readers.